# MySql Update when using data from the same row

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update a column `c` using php, but am I wrong in using the same rows data in the update statement?

It's this way since a user can update either his `first` or `second` name and I cannot charge things.

Will doing so cause any problems? Will this fail for any reason? Will c get updated first before a any time?

```
"update names set a = 'Jim', c = concat(a,' ',b);
```

First update `a`, then use `a` to update `c`. Is it safe?

```
 "id"   "a"     "b"     "c"
 "1"    "Jim"   "Doe"   "Jim Doe"
```

Comment: It's safe, but why store the concatenation at all?  Why not create it from the underlying columns upon data retrieval?

Comment: That's the way it is :-) There's no chance c will get updated before a does?

Comment: In that case, have you considered using a `BEFORE INSERT` [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html)?  I'd also suggest you consider using [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) instead, so that whitespace will not be added if either of the underlying columns is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's safe.  As documented under [`UPDATE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html):

> The second assignment in the following statement sets `col2` to the current (updated) `col1` value, not the original `col1` value. The result is that `col1` and `col2` have the same value. This behavior differs from standard SQL.
>
> ```sql
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```